# Implementing Minix 3.3 system call as libc library call

Tags: c, makefile, minix

I've been following this tutorial to create a system call in Minix.

http://homepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk/nick.cook/csc2025/minix/syscall-exercise1.html

I can use the system call correctly when I use _syscall and now I would like to create a libc library function to allow it to be easily used. However, following the last steps of the tutorial are not working for me. When I try to compile my code, I receive undefined reference to [my library function]. I've added the prototype to unistd.h, I think something is going wrong in my Makefile. All I did was add SRCS += myfile.c. Is there something more I need to do?

Comment: To clarify, myfile.c exists, contains my library function, and is in the same folder as Makefile.inc

Comment: Are you able to succeed when you follow the tutorial exactly (ie. implementing a library function named `printmsg()` in a source file named `printmsg.c`?

Comment: It appears to be slightly out of date, I followed it the best I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I was putting SRCS+=... in libc/sys/Makefile.inc but this Makefile is mostly under a conditional which I just realized is false. I moved over to libc/misc and added everything there and it worked like a charm.